# Matching values from two columns with the values of two columns in a sub-query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a problem I can't really figure out, even though I thought I had the solution.

I think this is DB2 SQL by the way.

I have a customer number and a country code (extracted from a string using `SUBSTR`) which I don't want to find in combination in a subquery, like so:

```
SELECT    ku.orgnr                             AS customer , 
          Substr(bu.bank_account_swiftadr,5,2) AS country 
FROM      db811.bet_utl bu 
LEFT JOIN db811.henv_utl bh 
ON        bu.betaling_urn = bh.betaling_urn 
LEFT JOIN db811.betaling_status bs 
ON        bu.betaling_status = bs.betaling_status 
LEFT JOIN db811.kunde_orgnr ku 
ON        bu.kundenr = ku.kundenr 
WHERE     bu.kanal = 'N' 
AND       (ku.orgnr, Substr(bu.bank_account_swiftadr,5,2)) ;
```

Not in the results below

```
SELECT    ku.orgnr                             AS customer , 
          Substr(bu.bank_account_swiftadr,5,2) AS country , 
          COUNT(*)                             AS numberof 
FROM      db811.bet_utl_hist bu 
LEFT JOIN db811.kunde_orgnr ku 
ON        bu.kundenr = ku.kundenr 
WHERE 
and       bu.kanal = 'N' 
AND       bu.betalingsdato > '2016-01-01' 
GROUP BY  ku.orgnr , 
          substr(bu.bank_account_swiftadr,5,2);
```

This should work I though, but it seems to match on just one of them, and I need both to be true in order for me to exclude it with the `NOT IN.`

I assume I am missing something basic since I am quite new at this.

Comment: Some code, no sample data and no expected result... Make it easy to assist you! Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry. I will try to find good examples of data.

Comment: Would you at least paste the complete query? It's really hard to understand your question with the given data.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry. I tried to translate parts of it since the rest is not in English and I thought it might help.. but I will have a go at it and put it up here. What I'm trying to do is to match find when both x.Customerno  and x.Country are the same as in my main query. I thought I coudl do it with the method over, but no luck.